# How to split an array from an other array with the numbers of element to split in python

Tags: python, arrays, split

How to split an array from an other array with the numbers of element to split in python

Hi,

I have 2 arrays like this :

```
names = ['georges','albert','kate','bradley','elizabeth','william','louis','charles']
iters = [2,2,4]
```

And browsing my array 'iters', I want to have 3 arrays like this :

```
arr1 = ['georges','albert']
arr2 = ['kate','bradley']
arr3 = ['elizabeth','william','louis','charles']
```

The first array has 2 elements because my first element in my array 'iters' is 2.
The second array has 2 elements because my second element in my array 'iters' is 2.
And finally my last array has 4 elements because my last element in my array 'iters' is 4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

here is one way :

```
splited = []
prev = 0
for i in iters:
    splited.append(names[prev:i+prev])
    prev += i

print(splited)
```

output:

```
>> [['georges', 'albert'], ['kate', 'bradley'], ['elizabeth', 'william', 'louis', 'charles']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```py
arrs = [names[sum(iters[:i]):sum(iters[:i + 1])] for i in range(len(iters))]
```

then you will have:

```
print(arrs)
[['georges', 'albert'], ['kate', 'bradley'], ['elizabeth', 'william', 'louis', 'charles']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an iterator object on your `names` list. You can then loop over the elements of `iters` and use the current value to loop extract the elements of the `names` list by calling `next()` on the `iter`.

How about something like this?

```
iter_names = iter(names)

array1, array2, array3 = [
    [next(iter_names) for _ in range(k)] for k in iters
]
```

Here is a `for` example:

```
iter_names = iter(names)

new_lists = []

for k in iters:
    new_list.append([next(iter_names) for _ in range(k)])

# only necessary to keep the same var names you need
array1, array2, array3 = new_list
```

Comment: `iter` is really clever.. I though of using `.pop(0)` but this is so much better because it doesn't destroy the list.

Comment: `iter` and the `itertools` module are often overlooked for solutions like this.  Super handy.